# Input field changes size on append

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, autosize

Im trying to append html code to a table. After everything is okey, the field is not 100% width when i initiate the site. After appending rows the width are expanding a little more. After 10 rows are appended, THEN the field are 100% of its width.

[image: How to website looks when I append a row, after 10 rows all fields are 100% width]

Any suggestions were to look? Im using jquery and bootstrap and the field code are:
`< textarea class='form-control' form="reqFrom" id="port" name="DMZtoInsidePort[]" placeholder="80,443">< textarea>`

Comment: can you create a bootply or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: please post some code, i can't really help if i dont know what causing your problem, give us some html and js

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the size in css of the < td>, it happend because the size were set dynamically by the components

```
table > thead > tr > td:nth-child(3) {
   width: 180px;
}
```